# angular 8 Pipe to sort the data but its not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating an angular app for online exams. Trying to use pipes in it.
I am getting an array of exam through my data service.
I want to sort them on the basis of popularity so i created a pipe to do the job.
like this..

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'popular'
})
export class PopularPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    var popularTests =  value.filter(function(hero) {
      return hero.category ==  "Medical";
    });
    console.log(popularTests)// console is printing the array in the exact format i need 
   
  }

}
```

my problem is when i am using this in my html getting error

```
can not read undefined
```

I am new to this technology i followed the steps given in documentation but still no luck
any help will be helpful

Comment: You should return value inside transform method.

Comment: Could you post your template code and how you’re using the pipe?

Comment: Please post your html too, to see how you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there should be a return statement. Because to make it work you need to return the data.
Your pipe is working fine because you are printing data in the pipe through console.
add a return statment at last

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'popular'
})
export class PopularPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    var popularTests =  value.filter(function(hero) {
      return hero.category ==  "Medical";
    });
    console.log(popularTests)
    return popularTests;// this will do the job
   
  }

}
```

please paste your html if this still give you any error

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value. Imagine it like a real pipe - something comes in and something comes out. Rather than writing `var popularTests` you can directly write return statement like `return value.filter(...`.

Sidenote: Please use types. They are very helpful and one of the things that makes complex app development much easier.